# How to remove repetitive Ninject Bindings?

Tags: ninject, ninject-extensions

My Current GeneralBindings : Ninject Module

```cs
public class GeneralBindings : NinjectModule
    {
        public override void Load()
        {
            // Requires Ninject.Extensions.Conventions
            // This binds all interfaces to concretes of the same name eg IClass -> Class.
            Kernel.Bind(x => x.FromAssembliesMatching("Company.Project.Scm*")
                .SelectAllClasses()
                .Excluding(typeof(AffectedCables),
                    typeof(ApplicationConfigurations),
                    typeof(ApplicationErrors),
                    typeof(ApplicationLogEvents),
                    typeof(AppUsers),
                    typeof(AppUsersContract),
                    typeof(Areas)

                    // etc..

                )
                .BindAllInterfaces());
```

then

```cs
            Bind<IAffectedCables>().To<AffectedCables>()
                .InSingletonScope()
                .WithConstructorArgument("url", @"api/AffectedCables");

            Bind<IApplicationErrors>().To<ApplicationErrors>()
                .InSingletonScope()
                .WithConstructorArgument("url", @"api/AppErrors");

            Bind<IApplicationConfigurations>().To<ApplicationConfigurations>()
                .InSingletonScope()
                .WithConstructorArgument("url", @"api/AppConfigurations");

            Bind<IApplicationLogEvents>().To<ApplicationLogEvents>()
                .InSingletonScope()
                .WithConstructorArgument("url", @"api/AppEventLogs");

            Bind<IAppUsers>().To<AppUsers>()
                .InSingletonScope()
                .WithConstructorArgument("url", @"api/AppUsers");

            Bind<IAppUsersContract>().To<AppUsersContract>()
                .InSingletonScope()
                .WithConstructorArgument("url", @"api/AppUserContract");

            Bind<IAreas>().To<Areas>()
                .InSingletonScope()
                .WithConstructorArgument("url", @"api/Areas");

            // Etc...
...
```

Can anyone suggest how to do this better? I'm sure that someone can create a single line of code that will save the copy and pasting that I have to perform at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A blind shot, not tested, but I would try with an attribute

```
public class AutoBindWithRouteAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string Route { get; }

    public AutoBindWithRouteAttribute(string route = null)
    {
        Route = route;
    }
}
```

then

```
    // to bind your first block of code for classes not featuring the attribute
    kernel.Bind(
        x => x.FromAssembliesMatching("").SelectAllClasses()
            .Where(t => !t.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AutoBindWithRouteAttribute), false).Any())
           .BindAllInterfaces());

    // to bind your second block of code for classes featuring the attribute
    kernel.Bind(
        x => x.FromAssembliesMatching("").SelectAllClasses()
            .Where(t => t.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AutoBindWithRouteAttribute), false).Any())
            .BindWith(new BindingGenerator()));
```

where `BindingGenerator` is :

```
public class BindingGenerator : IBindingGenerator
{
    public IEnumerable<IBindingWhenInNamedWithOrOnSyntax<object>> CreateBindings(Type type, IBindingRoot bindingRoot)
    {
        var att =
            type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AutoBindWithRouteAttribute), false).FirstOrDefault() as
                AutoBindWithRouteAttribute;
        if (att == null) yield break;

        yield return (IBindingWhenInNamedWithOrOnSyntax<object>)bindingRoot
            .Bind(type.GetInterfaces().First())
            .To(type)
            .InSingletonScope()
            .WithConstructorArgument("url", att.Route ?? $"api/{type.Name}");
    }
}
```

usage would then be :

```
[AutoBindWithRoute()]
public class AffectedCables : IAffectedCables

[AutoBindWithRoute(@"api/AppErrors")]
public class ApplicationErrors : IApplicationErrors
```

Answer (score 0):

Following from jbl's excellent suggested solution, because I had

```
 public class AffectedCables : DataAccessBase<AffectedCableEntity>, IAffectedCables
    {
...
    }
```

`BindingGenerator` was binding `DataAccessBase` so I made a small change to use the related Interface instead:

```
public class BindingGenerator : IBindingGenerator
        {
            public IEnumerable<IBindingWhenInNamedWithOrOnSyntax<object>> CreateBindings(Type type,IBindingRoot bindingRoot)
            {
                var att =
                    type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AutoBindWithRouteAttribute), false).FirstOrDefault() as
                        AutoBindWithRouteAttribute;
                if (att == null) yield break;

                yield return (IBindingWhenInNamedWithOrOnSyntax<object>) bindingRoot
                    .Bind(type.GetInterfaces().First(x => x.Name == $"I{type.Name}"))
                    .To(type)
                    .InSingletonScope()
                    .WithConstructorArgument("url", att.Route ?? $@"api/{type.Name}");
            }
        }
```